# Haskell-like libraries for Standard ML

Tags: functional-programming, sml

Can anyone recommend a library extension for Standard ML with similar strength as, and preferrably looking like, Prelude for Haskell? Preferrably one that works for many ML implementations, i.e. built with only the existing standard library and itself.

One library I have found is [MyLib](https://github.com/mortenbp/mylib), which does not resemble Prelude particularly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SML/NJ lib](http://smlnj.cs.uchicago.edu/dist/working/110.76/smlnj-lib.tgz) contains quite substantial functionality, most of which should be portable to any SML implementation. You can find the manual [here](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/).